# excel formula help on 2 sheets

Tags: excel-formula

i have a excel workbook with these two sheets in it. I am trying to sepearate product by Type into separate columns as shown on sheet 2. Any help how to do this in in excel, by reading sheet 1 and getting results into sheet 2. Thanks in Advance !!

SHEET 1

```
product    price     type
A           $10.98    PD
B           $54.89    SLP
C           $74.99    PD
D           $82.99    PD
E           $54.76    SLP
F                     
G           $76.99    PD
```

SHEET 2

```
Product    PD       SLP
A          $10.98
B                   $54.89
C          $74.99 
D          $82.99
E                   $54.76
F
G          $76.99
```

Answer (score 0):

I have put everything into one table for better view:

[both tables next to each other](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G2yHN.png)

In column G i think I have written:

=If($G$1=Table1[@type];INDEX(Table1[[Product]:[price]];Match(F2;Table1[Product]);2);"")

*Original in German: =WENN($G$1=Tabelle1[@type];INDEX(Tabelle1[[Product]:[price]];FINDEN(F2;Tabelle1[Product]);2);"")*